# Cannot seem to cast void* to struct in c++

Tags: c++, struct

I have a very simple method with the following prototype:

```
void *station_0(void* p1);
```

I am calling it like this:

```
product_record r;
pthread_create(thread, NULL, station_0, (void *)&r);
```

Inside this method all I need to do is cast `p1` to an already defined struct `product_record`, I am currently trying this inside of my method:

```
product_record p = (product_record)p1
```

but the compiler complains on that line(above) saying `error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]`

I don't think I understand this warning at all. Why cannot I simply cast a  `void*` to my struct?

Comment: Maybe you meant `product_record *p = (product_record *)p1;`

Comment: It's not clear from your post: is the pointer actually *pointing to* an instance of your struct? Or did you mean something else?  It might help to add in the code where you call this function.

Comment: It will be pointing to an instance of my struct? I will be using pthread_create to pass the address using `&` and casting the address as void*. From this method I need to cast the void* back to my struct instance.

Comment: So your code is like this: `product_record r;  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, station_0, (void *)&r);` ?

Comment: Yes, will be. Im dealing with compiler errors before I actually fully implement my threads but I will most certainly cast the address of my product record to send it to the thread

Comment: OK. Also would be good to clarify whether you want to work on the original `product_record` you passed in, in the same memory location; or whether you want the thread to take a copy of it

Comment: Definitely work on the original passed in. Im confused as to which is appropriate in my situation. If I'm casting the address of an instance of an already existing `product_record` then I should definitely just be using your first comment and creating a pointer to the address?.. which would be a `product_record` pointer that point to the address of the actual instance which is sort of a ** at that point..

Comment: Yes, you need to convert `p1` to `product_record *`, not `product_record`, because it is pointing to a product record.  This isn't "sort of a **" or anything. See Ed Heal's answer.  You can then go on to access the struct via pointer, or you can create a C++ reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need two steps - convert the void pointer to a `product_record` pointer and then de-reference that. This can be done in the line

```
product_record p = *(static_cast<product_record *>(p1));
```

Comment: note: this will make a copy of the struct; in order to operate in-place on it then change `p` to `&p`

Comment: Thank you this works well. -And gives me the record which is what I need. Working with the pointer works as well but I don't have to convert many  methodCall.foo() to method->foo() this way. Accepted

Comment: Tell me please how to convert back?